# Replace value in array/object php

Tags: php, arrays, object, replace

In the array/object below, how would I iterate through it and replace for instance SIEcat7 with test and SIEcat8 with test2. Trying below but have problems accessing the right level

Code

```
foreach($data as $i => $item) {
   if ($i[0] = "SIEcat7") {
       $i[0] = "test";
   }  
}
```

Object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [SIEcat7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => test1
            [amount] => 1 000.00

        )

    [SIEcat8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => test2
            [amount] => 0.00

        )



)
```

to become

```
stdClass Object
(
    [test1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => test1
            [amount] => 1 000.00

        )

    [test2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => test2
            [amount] => 0.00

        )



)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop? If it is just an object with 2 properties you do not need loop for it

Comment: `=` _sets_ a variable. `==` compares it. You're currently setting the variable in your if-expression.

Comment: please see updated question, it is not only 2, just used 2 as an example

Comment: What's wrong with @FrankerZ's answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should simply access `SIEcat7` using `$i`, not `$i[0]` as `$i` is not an array.

Additionally, to access properties of a class, you should simply just access them directly:

```
$data->SIEcat7
```

To replace the property of `SIEcat7` with `test`, it's as simple as:

```
$data->test = $data->SIEcat7;
unset($data->SIEcat7);
```